# Avoid construction of new objects if the class can operate stateless

Tags: java, performance, factory

(This question was closed on code review so I think I should ask here)

Let's say I have a factory like this (it's from an interview):

```
public class ControllersFactoryImpl implements ControllersFactory {

    private final SessionKeeper sessionKeeper;
    private final ScoreKeeper scoreKeeper;

    public ControllersFactoryImpl(final SessionKeeper sessionKeeper, final ScoreKeeper scoreKeeper) {
        this.sessionKeeper = sessionKeeper;
        this.scoreKeeper = scoreKeeper;
    }

    @Override
    public Controller makeLoginController(final int userId) {
        return new LoginController(userId, sessionKeeper);
    }

    @Override
    public Controller makePostUserScoreController(final int levelId, final String session, final int score) {
        return new AddScoreController(levelId, session, score, sessionKeeper, scoreKeeper);
    }

    @Override
    public Controller makeHighScoreController(final int levelId) {
        return new HighScoreController(levelId, scoreKeeper);
    }
}
```

since one of the requirements was to handle several call at the time (like millions) they told me that this solution could be improved because in this way we had a huge spawning of new objects (since I'm always calling new) that are doing a single stateless operation and the garbage collector could run into problems trying to clean them.

`Controller` is an interface that has a single method `execute()`.

Avoiding the usage of constructor is something that is puzzling me because the only way I can think of it, is to give to the execute method a var-args argument and I don't really like that solution because the code is not really readable in that way.

Do you have any alternatives?

This is the code for the controller:

```
public interface Controller {
    String execute();
}
```

And this is where the controller is used:

```
Controller controller = null;
try {
    if (exchange.isGet()) {
        final Matcher mLogin = loginPattern.matcher(path);
        if (mLogin.matches()) {
            controller = factory.makeLoginController(Integer.parseInt(mLogin.group(1)));
            contentType = TEXT_PLAIN;
        }
        Matcher mHighScore = highScorePattern.matcher(path);
        if (mHighScore.matches()) {
            controller = factory.makeHighScoreController((Integer.parseInt(mHighScore.group(1))));
            contentType = TEXT_CSV;
            exchange.setContentDisposition("attachment; fileName=data.csv");
        }
    } else if (exchange.isPost()) {
        final Matcher mScore = userScorePattern.matcher(path);
        if (mScore.matches()) {
            final Matcher mSession = sessionKeyPattern.matcher(httpExchange.getRequestURI().getQuery());
            if (mSession.matches()) {
                final Scanner s = new Scanner(httpExchange.getRequestBody());
                final int score = Integer.parseInt(s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "0");
                controller = factory.makePostUserScoreController(Integer.parseInt(mScore.group(1)), mSession.group(1), score);
                contentType = TEXT_PLAIN;
            }
        }
    }
    if (controller != null) {
        exchange.sendOk();
        buildResponse(exchange, controller, contentType);
    } else exchange.sendNotFound();

} catch (ExpiredSessionException e) {
    exchange.sendUnauthorized();
    exchange.setContentType(TEXT_PLAIN);
    exchange.setContentType("Session Expired");
} catch (Exception e) {
    log(e.getMessage());
    httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(500, 0);
} finally {
    httpExchange.getResponseBody().close();
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm aware of the if-else situation but with that amount of time I didn't have the time to refactor this part.

It's possible to change the code the way you want.

```
private void buildResponse(Exchange exchange, Controller controller, String contentType) throws IOException {
    exchange.setContentType(contentType);
    exchange.setContent(controller.execute());
}
```

Comment: What about the various controllers' code? Are they really stateless? And where is the `execute()` method called?

Comment: @RealSkeptic added what you requested. controller.execute is the output of the response. Yes they are stateless, the parameters passed in the constructor of the controllers are used in the execute and then the object is lost.

Comment: I think to get good quality answers you should probably explain what the assignment was and how much of the code is of your own design.

Comment: it's all my design, it was an interview with writing a program from scratch

Comment: OK, but what was the original task? It seems to be something along the lines of MVC or REST, and my guess is that you shouldn't have been using a factory like this at all, but perhaps it was required in the task.

Answer (score 1):

> since one of the requirements was to handle several call at the time (like millions) they told me that this solution could be improved because in this way we had a huge spawning of new objects (since I'm always calling new)

This sounds like a very very premature optimization. Does the program do any real work, like reading a file or iterating something? If so, then many bigger objects get created and caring about the controller creation is ridiculous.

Anyway, there's a `Scanner` allocated.

---

Your controller is not really stateless, it's immutable at best. Its state consists e.g. of `levelId, session, score, sessionKeeper, scoreKeeper`.

> execute method a var-args argument

This means a creation of an array... about the same overhead you wanted to avoid.

---

Anyway, it looks like the controller currently just complicates the design and you might be better off not using it. However, as the program grows, you may see that using a controller is a good idea as it nicely separates different actions.

*I'd just try it out as is. Get millions of requests, determine the bottleneck, and redesign it in case of problems. Till you run into performance problems, keep your design as clean as possible.*

Clean design means flexible design and that's the best starting point for optimizations. Code perfectly optimized for imaginary problems is a non-maintainable mess, getting slow in face of real problems and hopeless to improve.

---

If you really had to eliminate the controller creation, then you can't store any information in them. So you could create an

```
enum Controller {
    LOGIN {
        ...
    }
    POST_USERS_SCORE {
        ...
    }
    HIGH_SCORE {
        ...
    }

    abstract execute(int levelId, String session, int score);
}
```

where each implementation would ignore the arguments it doesn't need. This is a bit messy, but not as messy as mutable design could get. With mutable controllers you could pool and recycle them, but this is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Hi, it's stateless in the sense that those parameters are passed as arguments because I want to keep the execute interface, if you pass them as parameters of the execute, it's basically the same.

Comment: BTW: it's not premature optimization, it's a question in an interview, I was just not able to find an alternative solution to avoid construction of controllers. PS: the question was basically: "so if you have millions of calls you get so many new that the garbage collector is not able to do its job"